# Query problem - insert in JDBC (double quotes, single quote)

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I've a stupid problem that I cannot resolve. I'm learning Java and I'm new with this. My case is:

// ad a person into db

```
public static void aggiungiPersona(int id, String nome, String cognome, int anni, String sesso, 
                                  String indirizzo, String numTel, String email) {

    try {
             // create query
        String query = String.join("", "insert into persone (id, nome, cognome, anni, sesso, indirizzo, numTel, email) VALUES (",
                
                Integer.toString(id), ", '",
                nome, "', '", 
                cognome, "', ", 
                Integer.toString(anni), ", '",
                sesso, "', '", 
                indirizzo, "', '",
                numTel, "', '",
                email, "', ",
                 ")"

                );
```

I know that the problem is in quotes or double quotes, but where?

Comment: You may want to print the query to see how it looks .

Comment: Please learn about prepared statements and use them. Do not ever concatenate values into a query string, it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. In any case, your problem is not with quotes, but with a trailing comma.

Comment: @Arnaud is right. Print the query value, try to execute it using a database tool and read the error. (btw, I think the error is related to the last `,` after email)

Comment: Ok it was the last comma, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a prepared statement here which handles the proper escaping of your literal value:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO persone (id, nome, cognome, anni, sesso, indirizzo, numTel, email) ";
sql += "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, Integer.toString(id));   // use ps.setInt(1, id) if id be integer column
ps.setString(2, nome);
ps.setString(3, cognome);
ps.setString(4, Integer.toString(anni)); // use ps.setInt(4, anni) for anni integer column
ps.setString(5, sesso);
ps.setString(6, indirizzo);
ps.setString(7, numTel);
ps.setString(8, email);
int row = ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(row);
```